# If all data is entered, save it to coredata! - Swift

Tags: swift

I want to save data to core data. But if all text fields are full, save the core data. How can I do that?

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
let newSOS = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "SOS", into: context)


if forWhatText.text == "" {
        makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Please, add forwhat!")
    } else {
        newSOS.setValue(forWhatText.text, forKey: "forWhat")
    }
    
    if phoneName.text == "" {
        makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Please, add Phone Name!")
    } else {
        newSOS.setValue(phoneName.text, forKey: "phoneName")
    }
    
    if phoneNumber.text == "" {
        makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Please, add Phone Number!")
    } else {
        if let intNumber = Int(phoneNumber.text!) {
            newSOS.setValue(intNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
        }
    }
    
    if messageText.text == "" {
        makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Please, add message text!")
    } else {
        newSOS.setValue(messageText.text, forKey: "sosMessage")
    }
    
    newSOS.setValue(UUID(), forKey: "id")
    
    if choosenLatitude == nil && choosenLongtitude == nil {
        makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Please select your location on the map for emergencies!")
    } else {
        newSOS.setValue(choosenLatitude, forKey: "latitude")
        newSOS.setValue(choosenLongtitude, forKey: "longtitude")
    }
    
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("basarili")
    } catch {
        print("kaydolmadı")
    }
```

Comment: First get and validate input and _then_ create and store your managed object, now you are doing everything at once which makes the flow more complicated.

Comment: Hey, Actually I don't understand the question. The text fields are complete, save the core data otherwise show an alert or toast "Please enter the text", Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have first to check all validation then create an object and save it in Core Data.

Like This...

```
guard let forWhatTextString = forWhatText.text,
      forWhatTextString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count > 0 else {
    makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Please, add forwhat!")
    return
}

guard let phoneNameString = phoneName.text,
      phoneNameString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count > 0 else {
    makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Please, add Phone Name!")
    return
}

guard let phoneNumberString = phoneNumber.text,
      phoneNumberString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count > 0 else {
    makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Please, add Phone Number!")
    return
}

guard let phoneNumberInt = Int(phoneNumberString) else {
    makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Please, add Correct Phone Number!")
    return
}

guard let messageTextString = messageText.text,
      messageTextString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count > 0 else {
    makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Please, add message text!")
    return
}

guard choosenLatitude != nil,
      choosenLongtitude != nil else {
    makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Please select your location on the map for emergencies!")
    return
}

guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
let newSOS = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "SOS", into: context)

newSOS.setValue(forWhatTextString, forKey: "forWhat")
newSOS.setValue(phoneNameString, forKey: "phoneName")
newSOS.setValue(phoneNumberInt, forKey: "phoneNumber")
newSOS.setValue(messageTextString, forKey: "sosMessage")
newSOS.setValue(UUID(), forKey: "id")
newSOS.setValue(choosenLatitude, forKey: "latitude")
newSOS.setValue(choosenLongtitude, forKey: "longtitude")

do {
    try context.save()
    print("basarili")
} catch let err {
    print("kaydolmadı")
    print("Error is => ", err)
}
```

Hope you this helpful.